# How to parse json accepted from android app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

how to parse json data sent from android app. Suppoce i have a method in my controller inside which i have to parse this json data.

Suppoce android app is able to send json to provided url. As i believe in order to get data from android app I have to provide some url to the android application.

The major question is where is that json is stored, do I access via parameters hash?

Comment: is your android app sending the json data with request and you wanted to access it in params?

Comment: @AmitSharma,  it sends data via post. Im new to that topic, I think i should provide some link to my controller method which will handle data.

Comment: can you provide some example of json data?

Comment: @AmitSharma, any simple data, the question is how does generally that json is extracted in rails controller method, after searching in google i found smth. like JSON.parse etc. but can not figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in controller create one method and call it in before_action
e.g.

```
before_action :parse_json_data_to_params

def parse_json_data_to_params
  params.merge!(ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.raw_post))
end
```

plese dont forget to write `except` block in front of bfore_action because it will raise an error for get requests.